# How to used select and where condition in core data in objective c

Tags: objective-c, core-data

How can I used `Select` and `where` condition in core data in Objective-C?

```
Select empid,empname where depiid=112
```

How can I write this type of query in Core Data?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSFetchRequest` to select rows on `CoreData`

```
var objectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? {

        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return nil
        }

        return appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    }



if let context = objectContext {
  let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "EntityName")
  fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "depiid = %d", 112)

            do {
                let results = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
             print(result)
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate ;

NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@“TableName” inManagedObjectContext:appDelegate.managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@“depId == %@",[NSNumber numberWithNumber:num]];

[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
[request setPropertiesToFetch:
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@“empId”, @“empName”,  nil]];  
fetchRequest.entity = entityDescription;
fetchRequest.predicate = predicate;    
NSError *error;
NSArray *resultsArray = [appDelegate.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

Comment: Why `NSDictionaryResultType`?

Answer (score 0):

You use a predicate to filter results, this is your `WHERE`

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = Emp.fetchRequest;

// WHERE
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"depiid = %d", id];

// ORDER BY
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"depiid" ascending:YES]];

// LIMIT
fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1;

NSError *error;
NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
if (!objects) {
    // Error
}

Emp *emp = objects.firstObject;

NSLog(@"empid: %@, emp.id);
NSLog(@"empname: %@", emp.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: 
          "CompetitionPlayer", in: managedContext)
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>()
    request.entity = entity
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "competitionID = %d", 2)
    request.predicate = predicate

    
    let res = try! managedContext.fetch(request) as! [NSManagedObject]
    
    return res
```

Comment: In core data, NSPredicate is like were condition in SQLite